# Conversion: Array to Json automatically

Tags: python, arrays, json

How to make this script automatically concatenate the array? So that it is not necessary to pass the indices, example: `arr[0] ... arr[n]`. Where `val1, val2 ... val(n)`, is automatically assigned in an increasing way, example: `val1, val2, val3 ...` and so on. That way the array could have N values ​​and all would be transformed into Json automatically

```
import json

arr = ['MyValue1', 'MyValue2']
list = [{"labels": {"val1": arr[0], "val2": arr[1]}}]

print(json.dumps(list))
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "labels": {
        "val1": "MyValue1",
        "val2": "MyValue2"
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem like a good idea. Why not store the labels as a list?

Comment: the idea is to store it in a database column in json format

Comment: suggests something different?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-json.html

Comment: Why not use this JSON output instead? `{"labels": ["MyValue1", "MyValue2"]}`

Comment: Yes, I can use it, but when exist "My Value3"?

Comment: `{"labels": ["MyValue1", "MyValue2", "MyValue3"]}` of course. Or in general: `json.dumps({"labels": arr})`.

Comment: @Thomas thanks a lot!

Comment: @superbrain thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use dictionary comprehension:

```
import json

arr = ['MyValue1', 'MyValue2']
list = [{"labels": {"val%d"%(i+1):e for i,e in enumerate(arr)}}]

print(json.dumps(list))
```

Alternatively:

```
import json

arr = ['MyValue1', 'MyValue2']
list = {"labels": arr}

print(json.dumps(list))
```

Comment: Perfect, I just wanted a performatic way to do that, thanks!

Comment: No problem. An alternative would be to do something like this 

list = [{"labels": arr}]

You can have ordered lists in json, so there isn't a need to have a new dictionary. Of course, either option is fine

Comment: Now I was in doubt, which would be the most performer?

Comment: Anyway, could you attach the other option to your answer? We leave it to people in the future with the same doubt to decide which approach they think is best to follow for their problem

Comment: @LuisHenrique dictionary comprehension is an extra operation and an extra data structure, so I would say it is better to just have the list in the dictionary. You could also get rid of the square brackets as Thomas suggested in their comment as you can dump a dictionary with json

Comment: @LuisHenrique I shall do

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and support